# How to create an abstract syntax tree for a*(b+c)*d

Tags: syntax, compiler-construction, tree, abstract, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm confused as to how to represent the brackets in the AST. I know how to make a parse tree, a friend told me that AST will not contain the brackets , which I am unable to verify from any texts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend is right, the abstract syntax tree will not contain the parentheses. The parentheses only control the structure of the tree, they do not themselves appear in the tree.

So `a*(b+c)` would create a tree where `a` is the left child of `*` and the right child is another subtree where `b` and `c` are the children of `+`. Whereas `a*b+c` and `(a*b)+c` both would create a tree where the root is `+`, `*` with the children `a` and `b` is the left child of `+` and `c` is the right child of `+`.

> which I am unable to verify from any texts

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Tree) on abstract syntax trees:

> The syntax is "abstract" in not representing every detail appearing in the real syntax. For instance, grouping parentheses are implicit in the tree structure

Answer (score 3):

The standard wisdom for ASTs is that they don't contain parentheses from expressions.
That's actually just a matter of taste.  You can do it either way.

The point of abstraction is that *some* detail is dropped.

One might decide to drop other details than the parentheses; you still get an abstract syntax tree.  As an example, if you take fully concrete syntax tree, and drop all the terminal nodes that have fixed spellings (including '+', 'IF', and '('), you get a fine abstract syntax tree.

I build a program analysis and transformation tool that does this kind of abstraction (and several others) automatically from the raw grammar.  It has some very nice benefits:

- When building a parser from the grammar,  you can automatically construct the AST without manually writing any code.  This really matters when building and maintaining a large grammar like C++14 and IBM COBOL.   Yes, a (...) node shows up in the tree, but the concrete tokens for '(' and ')' do not.
- It is easier to regenerate source text from the AST automatically.   If you don't keep the parentheses nodes around, it is bit of effort to recover where to insert them when prettyprinting.
- If  you write patterns and code transformations in the surface syntax of langauge of interest (which we do), you write them with parentheses anyway.  And the matcher doesn't care if it has to match an "extra" node.  So in using the trees, this mostly isn't a problem.  (Once in a while we'll write rules that remove nested parentheses, but this is a pretty simple to write).